# android:configChanges="screenSize" parameter is taking portrait height in landscape mode

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I'm kind of confused here,I'm creating one application with supporting both portrait and landscape modes.I'm noticing a strange behaviour with "screenSize" parameter as the layout takes full portrait height of the device in landscape mode.Does anybody face the same issue.I'm really stuck here any help would be great.

Comment: What do you mean "the layout takes full portrait height of the device in landscape mode"? Can you attach a screenshot or something?

Comment: @Karakuri updated my question,please check.

Comment: Using the `configChanges` attribute is generally not good practice. What reason do you have for using it?

Comment: Tried for landscape without recreating/reloading the screen

Comment: Again, unless you have a very compelling reason to do so, evading configuration changes with `configChanges` is a bad thing to do. You should learn how to handle configuration changes properly, particularly because there are a great deal many other configuration changes that you do not handle which will cause the same re-create you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Karakuri thanks for your suggestion, i tried so many other options,even tried with two different layouts.But the problem is all other options are re-creating the screen which my client doesn't want,so i came up with this option.If you have any other solutions without re-create I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry @venky, there are no other options that avoid recreate, that's just how Android works. The more time you spend trying to fight the system, the more frustrated you will be. Perhaps you should start a new question asking how to handle a configuration change that retains whatever state you are trying not to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Inside your activity tag

Happy coding :)

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" this is what i have given in manifest

Comment: Hmmm... Hide `keyboardHidden`? :)

Comment: Yeah,hiding the keyboard by default when coming to the activity.it's requirement

Comment: Not understand. Activity in portrait mode viewed ok? Or how?

Comment: In portrait mode,activity looking absolutely ok,in lanscape mode only half-screen is visible

Comment: In screenshot all normally. TextView is match_parent?

Comment: Your toolbar don't view?

Comment: It's not textview,it's a webview is match_parent.And I'm hiding toolbar by making "visiblity:gone"

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, normally, when a configuration value changes that can affect the UI of your current activity happens, Android destroys the activity, then recreates it with the new configuration.  This is the preferred method and what happens when you don not have "orientation" or "screenSize" in your android:configChanges attribute.  If your app doesn't have any state (other than stuff Android automatically handles, like type in field values), then it should work fine.  If you do have some state values, then you should save that state using OnSaveInstanceState, or a ViewModel, and restore that state when the activity is recreated.

When you use the "android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" attribute it tells Android not to destroy and then recreate the activity when the size/orientation changes.  Instead it will call onConfigurationChanged() in your activity, and it is up to you to manually refresh the UI.

All of this is documented here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

I would recommend taking the android:configChanges attribute out of your activity altogether.  To prevent the softkeyboard from appearing initially, you can use the attribute:

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"